# How to set clean Image on Button in ios(Xamarin)

Tags: ios, image, button, xamarin.ios

I am new to Xamarin and iOS. I am setting Image on `Button` via both the way design and programatically.

**Design Way :**

[image]

my Image name is `Pen.png`.

**Programatically Way :**

```
btnEditAccount.SetImage(UIImage.FromFile("Pen.png"), UIControlState.Normal);
```

But in Both case My Image not set well. It Complete White Image. But on Button it display below Image.

**Output :**

[image]

**I Expect :**

[image]

Is there any Property I miss for my understing ?

How to set full white Image on Button.

Any Help be Appreciated.

Comment: in place of set image to button set background image to button.
Background is mention below the Image field as your screenshot shows.

Comment: @Maddyヅヅ I have set same Background color but not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I set `TintColor` to `Button` Image and it will solve the Probelm.

Programatically this way

```
btnEditAccount.SetImage(UIImage.FromFile("Pen.png"), UIControlState.Normal);
btnEditAccount.TintColor = UIColor.White;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
button.setImage(UIImage.init(named: "icon (5).png"), forState: .Normal)
 button.tintColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

[image]

Comment: first of all thanks for your reply. But I have solve the issue see my below answer and also I am using Xamarin with `C#`.